# Showing ${G^n}$ is isomorphic to ${G/}$ ${G_n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

Take ${G^n}$ to be {${g^n:} $ g in G}, ${G_n}$ to be {g in G: ${g^n = 1}$}. Show that ${G^n}$ is isomorphic to ${G/}$${G_n}$.

I'm not sure how to go about proving this. My initial thought was to use one of the isomorphism theorems, particularly the first one. If I can find a homomorphism from G to H s.t. the image of the homomorphism is ${G^n}$ and the kernel is ${G_n}$ I could use the first isomorphism theorem, but I'm not sure if this is a good idea.

Intuitively, ${G_n}$ seems to be all elements of order n in G. Why do the cosets of ${G}$ isomorphic to ${G^n}$?

Comment: Your homomorphism idea is pretty good! Is there an obvious homomorphism from $G$ to $G^n$?

Comment: Is $G$ abelian? If so, the homomorphism idea is a good bet. Note as an aside that $G_{n}$ is the set of all elements of order DIVIDING $n$, not of order $n$.

Comment: Ooo great suggestion @MikeMiller. I was thinking this: The obvious homomorphism from G to ${G^n}$ would just be the elements of G being mapped to the elements of ${G^n}$ (taking g to ${g^n}$). The image of this homomorphism would be ${G^n}$. I was wondering how to find the kernel of a homomorphism?

Comment: The image of your homomorphism must be $G^{n}$. However, there is an obvious homomorphism (given $G$ is abelian) which surjects onto $G^{n}$, which I imagine is what Mike was suggesting.

Comment: @jstnchng It does not have to be $G^n$ as long as $H$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $G^n$. Using $G^n$ is sufficient as long as the homomorphism you choose is onto.

Comment: The kernel of the $n$th power map on $G$ is precisely the set of elements of $G$ with order dividing $n$, since these are the elements whose image is $1$ under $g \mapsto g^{n}$.

Comment: As the others have said, $G$ needs to be abelian for this to work; otherwise there's no obvious reason $G_n$ and $G^n$ should even be subgroups.

Comment: Oh I see!!! Thanks so much for your help everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work, $G$ has to be an abelian group (else $G^n$ might not be a subgroup!)

The homomorphism idea discussed in the comments is good.  You are right, the obvious homomorphism is $\phi: G \to G^n$ with $\phi(g) = g^n$.  (You should check this is a homomorphism and its image is $G$; both of these are easy.)

What is the kernel of $\phi$?  Well it is exactly those elements $g$ such that $g^n = 1$...